# Can I make a Jenkins job that it can be seen only by me or can not be seen in the *all tab*

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Can I make a Jenkins job that it can be seen only by me or can not be seen in the *all tab*?
That means others can not see the job in the *all tab*. however, if others can see the jobs in other tabs,it's OK. the goal is let the other not to use the *all tab*, because there are too many jobs in that tab.
is there this kind of plugin in Jenkins?

Comment: Then it wouldn't be the all tab, would it?

Comment: No,it wouldn't.@stark

Comment: I think I got the answer. I can set another tab as default tab, then I can delete the All tab, then other people will not see the long list of the jobs

Comment: I think this is the answer to your question. You should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think I got the answer. I can set another tab as default tab, then I can delete the All tab, then other people will not see the long list of the jobs